# Inconsistent occurrence of Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, sax

I'm attempting to parse an XML using the SAXparser. The file in question is about 4.5 gigs large.  The job always fails with the same exception but at different locations in the XML.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15709953; columnNumber: 3; Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.

In this instance, it failed near line 15.7 mil. Upon subsequent runs, it failed at line 7 mil, 80 mil, 32 mil, etc.  I am streaming from a zip in s3 (though I tried streaming the file from my local with the same behaviour). The random lines that it fails on makes me suspect there is something going on with the stream instead of the file itself.

Comment: If you parse it using the local file (after downloading it just once), does it still exhibit the "different positions on different runs" behavior?

Comment: It does exhibit the same behavior (random lines causing exceptions)

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug somewhere in the Java code. Have you tried parsing it with .NET or similar?